# Contact Builder Confusion: How to configure contact builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I am having issues with Journey builder which I feel emanate from the way I have set up my data model in contact builder.

Here are the steps I have followed to configure contact builder.

**Steps**

1. Create an import activity to bring in customer records from the FTP
2. Create an attribute group in Data Designer. The name of the attribute group is Smith and Thunder (17 Attributes) [image]
3. I have linked this attribute to an existing data extension using a 1-1 relationship, contact key to id. [image][image].

**Issue**

1. After doing this, the email address does not appear as an option in the Channel address order.[image]
2. I am using a date-based event an an entry source. The event data extension is the MasterSusbcriberDE. When this event runs, contacts are admitted to it but it throws an **error binding data bound member** error.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "bind" a record you're sending to, the contact key for that contact needs to be in a "population". You can create a population by adding a sendable data extension to the Populations tab in Contact Builder explicitly or by adding a record to All Subscribers, MobileConnect contacts or MobilePush contacts. My advice would be to skip Populations tab in Contact Builder altogether, if you have a multi-business unit setup as you burn contacts quotas with each population - a Contact that exists in two Populations counts as two contacts, but an All Subscribers record counts as one contact, even if 1500 business units can send to them. Crazy, I know. If you have a single business unit setup, I'm still struggling with the need for Populations, unless you have a theoretical need for contacts with no email address. But wait...

Answer (score 0):

What you have configured under Contact Builder is right. Channel Address function has been deprecated by Marketing Cloud, so you don't need to do that anymore. 
The contacts that you are trying to inject into the journey should be already existing records for JB to be able to send them email.

> If no contact record exists in Marketing Cloud for a person
>   entering this journey, the journey does not admit that person.

Comment: Thanks Maneesh. I am not sure I understand your explanation as these contacts are admitted into the journey but don't get messages. How would I make them contacts from an import?

Comment: Can you try this - Just pick one of the contacts. Add it manually to All Subscribers and then try injecting it into the journey and see what happens